# Inyección de dependencia Identity - ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

estoy creando una API y me encontré con un problema. Quiero usar clases custom para trabajar con Identity. Tengo el siguiente código y al querer ejecutar una consulta al método Get() obtengo el siguiente error

```
**"Unable to resolve service for type 'Sample.API.Models.Identity.Stores.ApplicationUserStore' while attempting to activate 'Sample.API.Models.Identity.Managers.ApplicationUserManager'."**
```

Ya intenté configurar el archivo Startup.cs de varias formas, pero no logro que funcione. Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection servicesCollection)
    {
        servicesCollection.AddDbContext<MyIndentityContext>(currentOptions =>
            currentOptions.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        servicesCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIndentityContext>()
            .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            servicesCollection.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserManager>();
            servicesCollection.AddTransient<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationSignInManager>();
            servicesCollection.AddTransient<RoleManager<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleManager>();
            servicesCollection.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, ApplicationUserStore>();
            servicesCollection.AddTransient<IRoleStore<ApplicationRole>, ApplicationRoleStore>();

            ...

            ...

            ...
    }

    public class MyIndentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public MyIndentityContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
            IConfiguration configuration)
            : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Sample.API");
        }

    }

    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(ApplicationRoleStore roleStore,
            IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<ApplicationRoleManager> logger) : base(roleStore,
            roleValidators,
            keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<ApplicationSignInManager> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes) : base(userManager,
            contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(ApplicationUserStore userStore, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
            IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
            IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<ApplicationUserManager> logger) :
            base(userStore, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors,
                services, logger)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, MyIndentityContext>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleStore(MyIndentityContext dbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber)
            : base(dbContext, identityErrorDescriber)
        {}
    }

    public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, MyIndentityContext, string>
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore(MyIndentityContext dbContext, IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber)
            : base(dbContext, identityErrorDescriber)
        {}

    }

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {}

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole() { }

        public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) { }

        public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string roleDescription) : base(roleName)
        {
            Description = roleDescription;
        }

    }

public UserController(ApplicationUserManager applicationUserManager)
{
    _applicationUserManager = applicationUserManager;

    // GET: api/User/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<UserDTO> Get(int id)
    {

        var currentuser = await _applicationUserManager.FindByNameAsync("UN_NOMBRE");

        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar las clases ApplicationUserManager y ApplicationUserStore ?

Comment: Hola, están ahí. Pero estan vacias porque todavía no agregue metodos ni sobreescribi ninguno, de hecho todavia no lo necesito, pero lo quiero dejar funcionando para hacer todo después

Comment: Estoy desde el telefono, pero no puedo ver bien si tienes  IRepository inyectado , de no ser asi por lo pronto podrias hacerlo de esta forma .... services.AddScoped<IRepository, MemoryRepository>();

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código del método Configure()? Es ahí donde se establecen los middleware configurados previamente en ConfigureServices(), como por ejemplo usar el módulo Identity haciendo app.UseIdentity(); en dicho método Configure()